# Pass comment with svn commit in WSO2 Carbon

Tags: svn, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I'm using WSO2 Carbon along with SVN DepSync setup like the link below describes:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/Cluster/SVN-based+Deployment+Synchronizer

I wonder if there's a way to configure the carbon.xml to pass a comment along with every commit.

similar to this:

```
svn commit -m "pass this comment"
```

The documentation for carbon.xml doesn't mention an element for any kind of comment.

Comment: what is the use case of passing commit message?

Comment: @user6008415 : Do you think, is it scalable for each changes, providing commit message? What you are going to do with these commit messages?

Comment: We have a pre commit hook in our SVN requireing a particular set of information before the commit is accepted. Instead of changing the code in SVN a quickfix would be to set the string in a configuration file in WSO2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way for you to put your custom message with depsync in WSO2. You can check the code segment here
https://github.com/wso2/carbon-commons/blob/master/components/deployment-synchronizer/org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/deployment/synchronizer/subversion/SVNBasedArtifactRepository.java#L372

There message is set as "Commit initiated by deployment synchronizer". As mentioned in comments, having custom svn commit messages are not scalable